# Permission issue with custom post type - not added to menu - by plugin

Tags: posts, permissions, customization

I've created a custom post type and taxonomy like this...

```
   function register_post_type_products() {
            $labels = array( 'name' => _x('Produkter', 'post type general name'),
                        'singular_name' => _x('Produkt', 'post type singular name'),
                        'add_new' => _x('Lägg till', 'produkt'),
                        'add_new_item' => __('Lägg till produkt'),
                        'edit_item' => __('Redigera produkt'),
                        'new_item' => __('Ny Product'),
                        'view_item' => __('Visaproduct'),
                        'search_items' => __('Sök produkt'),
                        'not_found' => __('Inget kunde hittas'),
                        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Inget hittade i soptunna'),
                        'parent_item_colon' => '' );
            $args = array( 'labels' => $labels,
                        'public' => true,
                        'publicly_queryable' => true,
                        'show_ui' => true,
                        'query_var' => true,
                        'rewrite' => true,
                        'capability_type' => 'post',
                        'hierarchical' => true,
                        'menu_position' => null,
                        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail') );

        register_post_type( 'product' , $args );

        register_taxonomy("productcategory",
                            array("product"),
                            array("hierarchical" => true,
                            "label" => "Produktkategorier",
                            "singular_label" => "Produktkategori",
                            "rewrite" => true,
                            "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
                            "public" => true));

    }
    add_action('init', 'register_post_type_products');
```

Nothing strange it all. It works fine.

But then I wanted to rearrange som posts and I know that the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/ would fit my needs. BUT for some reason the "Re-order option" doesn't show up in the dashboard menu (admin menu). I know it works because there are other custom post types defined in the theme (I can't find how that is done though), and with those custom post type the re-order option appears.

When I try to go to the url (domain) + `edit.php?post_type=product&page=order-post-types-product` it says I don't have enough priveligies. Where should I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Just because I added the question here, I found it ... So ... easy... so irritating... but I hope this answer will help anyone else with this issue quicker!

changed `'hierarchical' => true` to `'hierarchical' => false` for the custom post type!